# Are questions automatically deleted if they are -1 without answers?

Tags: support, questions, automatic-deletion

A while ago I asked a question which received no answers and one downvote. I had kind of hoped that someday someone would know the answer or I'd build enough reputation points to bounty it without risking loss of my ability to comment.

I see that this question has been deleted by user *Community*. I can't see any feedback or reason. I did read https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions, but it wasn't clear whether deletion is automatic or just made more easy for others to vote on. I was under the impression that questions are usually not deleted if they're valid, merely ranked out of sight or closed/locked. Without any feedback I don't really want to rock the boat by undeleting it (assuming I can) in case it was deleted for a good reason.

If I undelete the question, or ask it again, will it be automatically deleted if it fails to get an answer in a certain time frame?

Comment: The autodeletions are mostly used to clear out **unanswerable** questions, so if you think your question is truly answerable, you can flag for a moderator to undelete your question. They're usually good about doing that.

Comment: Can you add a link to the question so that those of us with enough rep can see it and possibly offer constructive guidance?

Comment: @tripleee perhaps you can find it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3413047/bsafh?tab=questions)

Comment: @AdamJensen As far as I can tell, the profile only shows undeleted answers.

Comment: @triplee I'll admit I refrained from doing that because I'm not 100% that it wouldn't just be deleted for another reason. I think you might see what I mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517631/binding-to-a-different-active-directory-ldap-instance-in-powershell

Comment: Hmmmm, certainly looks fine to me, although I'm not very familiar with the topic.  Voted to undelete (2 more votes required).

Comment: @triplee thanks for undeleting it guys. Extra thanks to Vache because s/he put a bounty on it too and there is now a great answer. (I cant test until Monday).

Answer (score 29):

## [**Yes.**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006)

> [T]he Community user will delete questions in the following circumstances:
>
> **If the question is more than 30 days old, and…**
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
>
> […] it will be automatically deleted.

Comment: Kind of odd that the OP is not informed about it when it happens...

Comment: @icktoofay : Does it mean answering your own question would prevent deletion?

Comment: @user2284570 If you answer your own question with a "fake answer" it will probably be downvoted and deleted by other users. Also, if the question gets closed then it is deleted even if there are answers (and this answers don't have a positive score).

Comment: @Bakuriu : With something which don't look like a *fake answer* of course.

Comment: @Theolodis Are you (OP) informed in any way, if any of questions is closed in any other way, than auto-delete by Community user?

Comment: @trejder if it is closed? I believe so, but I can't tell as I did not yet have a question closed.

Comment: @Theolodis Sorry to dissapoint you, but not! :] I have many closed questions and I only learn, that they were closed, by revisiting them.